# Deve-se escrever “internet” com letra minúscula ou maiúscula?

Tags: ortografia, substantivos, maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

É comum vermos publicações conceituadas empregando ***internet*** ou ***Internet***. Parece que a rede mundial de computadores **Internet** está se tornando no substantivo comum ***internet***. Por quê? Isso ocorre também em outras línguas?

Qual a forma mais correta de se escrever internet?

Comment: http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/3391

Comment: @Artefacto, realmente existem alguns artigos na internet que falam sobre essa questão, mas não são conclusivos.  Esse link que você postou é interessante, no entanto, é de 2007. Fiz a pergunta aqui no Stack para ver se os colegas tem alguma novidade sobre o assunto, se isso ocorrem em outras línguas e o porquê.

Comment: Não estava a criticar a pergunta, queria apenas deixar um link relevante sem o trabalho de escrever uma resposta.

Answer (score 5):

O argumento para inicial maiúscula é *internet* ser o nome de uma entidade única, mas isto vai tendo cada vez menos peso, e quer em português quer em inglês a tendência crescente é escrever com minúscula.

*Internet* é uma redução de *internetwork*, que por por sua vez é formada pelo pseudoprefixo *inter-* (‘entre’) e *network* (‘rede (de ligações)’, como em *road network*, ‘rede de estradas’). Ver por exemplo [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=internet) ou o dicionário Houaiss, que traduz *internetwork* como ‘ligação entre redes’. A questão se a palavra é um nome próprio, *Internet*, ou nome comum, *internet*, coloca-se quer no português quer no inglês, e em inglês existem pilhas de artigos a discutir o assunto. Este [blogue do Oxford Dictionaries (5-4-2016)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190401111733/https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/04/05/should-you-capitalize-internet/) faz uma boa síntese do percurso da palavra (minha tradução):

> Na verdade, os primeiros usos da palavra, presente no Oxford English Dictionary desde 1974, foram com *i* minúsculo. Inicialmente havia muitas *internetes*—a palavra era usada para referir qualquer rede de computadores contendo ou ligando várias redes mais pequenas; mais tarde passou especificamente a referir a rede global que conhecemos hoje, que foi distinguida como “a Internet”, por oposição a “uma internet”. Não é incomum palavras assumirem uma forma com letra maiúscula num sentido particular visto como nome próprio (por exemplo, os norte-americanos chamam ao documento fundacional do seu governo federal “a Constituição”); no entanto, no caso de “a Internet”, por meados do anos noventa, a necessidade original de desambiguação estava em grande medida obsoleta, e a alguns escritores e editores a convenção da inicial maiúscula apresentava-se desnecessária, ultrapassada e inestética.

Este [“Should We Be Capitalizing the Word ‘Internet’”](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/should-you-be-capitalizing-the-word-internet/) publicado na revista de tecnologia Wired (19-10-2015), explica a razão de a distinção entre *a Internet* e *uma internet* já não ser necessária (minha tradução):

> A razão normalmente avançada para esta mudança no uso é que a internet e a web estão através do uso comum a passar de substantivos próprios—entidades únicas, com nomes—a substantivos genéricos. Com efeito, a maioria das pessoas (com a exceção dos ‘techies’) não sabem de nenhumas internetes para além da Internet—essa distinção deixou de ser relevante no uso corrente. E para muita gente mais nova que cresceu com a tecnologia, a internet é uma coisa banal—simplesmente mais um meio de comunicação, como o telefone, televisão e rádio.

Entretanto no inglês, *the internet* tem vindo a ganhar terreno a *the Internet*, embora em Abril de 2016, no vasto corpus reunido pelo Oxford Dictionaries [(ver blogue)](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/04/should-you-capitalize-internet/), *Internet* ainda vencesse por 54% contra 46%. Isto deve-se à América do Norte; no Reino Unido vencia *internet* por 75% contra 25%. Mas as coisas estão a mudar, e entretanto instituições norte-americanas de peso como a Associated Press e o New York Times [(ver artigo no NYT)](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/05/25/business/media/internet-to-be-lowercase-in-new-york-times-and-associated-press.html) decidiram passar a escrever *internet*, com minúscula.

Em português creio que a preferência por minúscula é ainda mais forte. Os dicionários são normalmente conservadores, mas já em 2003 a edição portuguesa do Houaiss dizia apenas “inicial por vezes maiúscula”; o dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa de 2001 traz apenas a grafia com minúscula; o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/internet) diz “muitas vezes, com inicial maiúscula” e no artigo enciclopédico escreve sempre com minúscula; a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/internet) diz, sem se comprometer para um lado ou para outro, “também com maiúscula”.

Note-se que coexistirem os dois entendimentos, nome próprio com maiúscula versus nome comum com minúscula, não é exclusivo de *internet*. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) diz que *universo* na aceção ‘conjunto de todas as coisas que existem ou se crê existirem’ se escreve por vezes com inicial maiúscula; o “por vezes” indica que mais normalmente se escreve com minúscula.

Answer (score 4):

Reproduzo [a resposta do Prof. Cláudio Moreno, “internet ou Internet”, em *Sua Língua*:](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/18/internet-ou-internet/)

> As duas formas ainda disputam a preferência do público, mas tudo indica que a vencedora, já definida, é a forma com a inicial minúscula. Essa mesma discussão está viva em outros idiomas, mas a tendência é claramente em direção à forma internet, que realmente parece mais lógica, pelo que vamos ver.
>
> Michael Quinion, o talentoso autor do sítio World Wide Words, diz que, no início, nos anos 60, o termo era escrito em minúsculas. Na década de 80, no entanto, passou a ser grafado com a inicial maiúscula, como se fosse um nome próprio — até recentemente, quando a espantosa divulgação desta rede globalizada pressionou a consciência dos falantes a considerarem-na um substantivo comum. Ela entrou em nossas vidas como o telefone, o rádio e a televisão, e aquele I em caixa alta foi se tornando cada vez mais estranho. É mais ou menos o que aconteceu com produtos industriais que se tornaram nomes genéricos, como a gilete, o bandeide e o xerox. Segundo Quinion, a importantíssima revista Wired terminou de adotar, como norma, internet, net e web definitivamente em minúsculas, o que representa um sinal de qual será a forma sobrevivente. Aqui no Brasil, para tua informação, tanto o Houaiss quanto o Aurélio preferem internet. Podes continuar com a tua maiúscula, mas verás cada vez mais adeptos da outra forma.

Answer (score 1):

Minúscula (a não ser no início da frase), conforme o [Portal da Lingua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=15889) : *internet*.

Comment: Assim como telefonia não se escreve com maiúsculas.

Comment: @Jorge Canelhas.  Esperava uma resposta mais completa. Por que é com letra minúscula? Parece que já foi escrita com letra maiúscula. Isso ocorre também em outras línguas?

Comment: Ja editei. :) acrescentei a página.

Comment: Por curiosidade, porque levei um -1 na minha resposta ?

Comment: @Jorge Canelhas, Internet não é um nome próprio, é um meio de comunicação.

Comment: Mas quem disse que era nome próprio?

Comment: Internet só poderia ser maiúscula se fosse uma personificação, e assim, referida como nome próprio. Além disso, não se encaixaria em nenhuma das outras possibilidades.

Comment: Sim, e ? Por isso fui downvoted ?

Comment: Jorge, temos um problema: o Portal da Língua Portuguesa, tal como os outros vocabulários ortográficos online ([Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) e [VOC da CPLP](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=57866)) indicam tudo com minúscula, mesmo *Deus*.

Comment: @AndréLyra, na verdade há quem considere a palavra como nome próprio: nesta interpretação, *a Internet* é uma entidade única, a rede global de computadores ligados segundo um protocolo específico. Vê [este artigo](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/3391) já indicado acima pelo Artefacto, e a minha resposta. Vários dicionários de português indicam que também se escreve com maiúscula. Mas o teu entendimento, que eu partilho, de que é apenas um meio de comunicação como televisão ou rádio, tem vindo a ganhar terreno.

Answer (score 1):

Internet é um acrônimo (sigla) para Interconnected Network. Como é uma sigla que se pronuncia como uma palavra, escrevendo-se Internet e não INTERNET. A grafia "internet" também não me parece aplicável.

Comment: Onde foste buscar essa ideia que uma sigla pronunciada como uma palavra se escreve apenas com inicial maiúscula? Isso é claramente falso. ONU, OTAN, PALOP pronunciam-se como uma palavra e escrevem-se com todas as letras maiúsculas. Por outro lado, há siglas que acabam por se trasnformar em substantivos: *óvni, radar, laser*. E se têm inicial maiúscula ou minúscula depende de serem substantivos próprios ou comuns; a discussão de *Internet* versus *internet* estaria aqui; mas é duvidoso considerá-la como sigla: os dicionários dizem que é redução de *internetwork*, como *foto* de *fotografia*

Answer (score -1):

A grafia preferível é "**Internet**", sendo uma **sigla pronunciável por uma palavra** referente à *International Network* (Rede Internacional de Computadores), diz a regra gramatical que a primeira letra será sempre maiúscula e as demais minusculas. Esta palavra é semelhante as palavras Interpol e Petrobrás.

> Fonte Rádio Oficial do Brasil:
>   http://www2.camara.leg.br/camaranoticias/radio/materias/PORTUGUES-NO-DIA-A-DIA/395972-INTERNET-COM-INICIAL-MAIUSCULA-OU-MINUSCULA.html

Comment: A Rádio Oficial do Brasil é capaz de não ser a autoridade mais competente em matéria de gramática. Os melhores dicionários de português―Houaiss, Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, Aulete—indicam *internet*, com minúscula, acrescentando apenas que também se vê com maiúscula. É duvidoso classificar *internet* como sigla: é uma redução de *internetwork*, tal como *foto* é redução de *fotografia*. O *inter-* não vem de *international*; é o prefixoide *inter-* que encontras em *interface, interligação*, etc.; significa ‘entre’; *network* é ‘rede de ligação’ (vem tudo no Houaiss).

Comment: No Brasil, a norma ortográfica é estabelecida por meio de Lei http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2007-2010/2008/decreto/d6583.htm Na Base XIX apresenta a regra para  maiúsculas e minúsculas @jacinto

Comment: Renato, a lei que indicaste simplesmente aprova o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, e ele não diz em lado nenhum que *internet* é uma sigla. E nota que mesmo palavras que começam como siglas passam a escrever-se com minúscula quando passam a ser entendidos como nome comum. É exemplo *laser*, escrito com minúscula, e que, essa sim, começou como a sigla de ***l**ight **a**mplification by **s**timulated **e**mission of **r**adiation*.